# Best way to cache in Node.js

Tags: node.js, caching

I am trying to find the best caching solution for a node app. There a few modules which can manage this. Most popular being: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache

But I found that responses are faster if I just save some results into a variable like:

```
var cache = ["Kosonsoy","Pandean","Ḩadīdah","Chirilagua","Chattanooga","Hebi","Péruwelz","Pul-e Khumrī"];
```

I can then update that variable on a fixed interval, is this also classed as caching? Are there any known issues/problems to this method. As it defiantly provides the fastest response times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it is faster as you use local memory to store the data.
For limited cache size this is good, but can quickly eat up all your process memory.

I would advise to use modules as there is a considerable amount of collaborative brainpower invested in them. Alternatively you can use a dedicated instance to run something like Redis to use as cache.

Alternatives aside, if you would stick with your solution I recommend small improvement.

Instead of

```
var cache = ["Kosonsoy","Pandean","Ḩadīdah","Chirilagua","Chattanooga","Hebi","Péruwelz","Pul-e Khumrī"];
```

try using objects as key value storage.

This will make searching and updating entries faster.

```
var cache = {"Kosonsoy":data,"Pandean":moreData,...};
```

Searching in array requires iterations while accessing the object is as simple as

```
var storedValue = cache["Kosonosoy"];
```

saving

```
cache[key] = value;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [many workers](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) you will have a duplicated cache for each one because they have no shared memory.

Of course, you can use it for small data. And keeping a data in a variable for an amount of time can be called caching for me.

Comment: For the past decade I have been using (on occasion) [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com) in my Java environment to cache data across a dozen Tomcat servers on AWS. Worked exceptionally well. I just did a search and it seems that they have a [Node.js client](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-nodejs-client) port. Don't know if it's commercial ready but definitely worth looking into.